# Error when applying change for aws_apigatewayv2_api resource on LocalStack

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, localstack

I'm trying to create an API gateway on LocalStack with terraform but I get this error:

```
aws_apigatewayv2_api.lambda: Creating...
╷
│ Error: error creating API Gateway v2 API: UnrecognizedClientException: 
│       status code: 403, request id: bd95aa42-75ab-42d1-9c9a-b95d9a58b3c8
│ 
│   with aws_apigatewayv2_api.lambda,
│   on main.tf line 131, in resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "lambda":
│  131: resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "lambda" {
│ 
╵
```

I'm following the tutorial from here:
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/lambda-api-gateway

Comment: Where is the code that creates this stack?

Comment: @MarkoE It's in the tutorial I wrote in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`API Gateway v2` is only [supported](https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/feature-coverage/) in **pro** version of `LocalStack`. So if you want to use it, please [buy](https://localstack.cloud/pricing/) the pro version.

Comment: Ok. I think this is the only explanation other than hostname configuration issues that I found through googling that makes sense.

They should at least return a different error when trying to use API Gateway V2 without a license.